# Test-SRTopology Fails to Create CIM Session to Local Host

Tags: windows, powershell, storage, windows-server-2019

We are trying to setup Storage Replication between two brand new Server 2019 VMs.  I have followed all the steps in Microsoft's guide (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/storage-replica/server-to-server-storage-replication) up to where we are supposed to test the replication.  When I run the following

```
Test-SRTopology -SourceComputerName SrcSrv01 -SourceVolumeName e: -SourceLogVolumeName g: -DestinationComputerName DestSrv02 -DestinationVolumeName e: -DestinationLogVolumeName g: -DurationInMinutes 30 -ResultPath c:\temp
```

I get the following error:

```
WARNING: WMI v2.0 could not create a CIM Session for SrcSrv01
Possible reasons are:
You specified an incorrect NetBIOS name or fully qualified domain name for the destination computer
You specified an IP address for the destination server. Only NetBIOS names or fully qualified domain names are allowed
The destination computer firewall is blocking access to PowerShell or WMI remoting
You are logged on to the source computer as a local user. You must use a domain user
You did not use CREDSSP credentials when running the Test-SRTopology cmdlet remotely from a management computer
The destination computer is not running or is not accessible over the network
The destination computer is not running the WMI service
WARNING: System.Exception
WARNING:    at Microsoft.FileServices.SR.Powershell.MIConnection.GetNamespace(String namespaceName, String computerName)
   at Microsoft.FileServices.SR.Powershell.TestSRTopologyCommand.GetNetBiosName(String ComputerName)
   at Microsoft.FileServices.SR.Powershell.TestSRTopologyCommand.BeginProcessing()
Test-SRTopology : WMI v2.0 could not create a CIM Session for fsgcm01
Possible reasons are:
You specified an incorrect NetBIOS name or fully qualified domain name for the destination computer
You specified an IP address for the destination server. Only NetBIOS names or fully qualified domain names are allowed
The destination computer firewall is blocking access to PowerShell or WMI remoting
You are logged on to the source computer as a local user. You must use a domain user
You did not use CREDSSP credentials when running the Test-SRTopology cmdlet remotely from a management computer
The destination computer is not running or is not accessible over the network
The destination computer is not running the WMI service
At line:1 char:1
+ Test-SRTopology -SourceComputerName fsgcm01 -SourceVolumeName e: -Sou ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Test-SRTopology], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TestSRTopologyFailure,Microsoft.FileServices.SR.Powershell.TestSRTopologyCommand
```

If I try and do a New-CIMSession Localhost it works fine.  However, if I do a New-CIMSession SrcSrv01 I get the following error:

```
New-CimSession : The WinRM client sent a request to an HTTP server and got a response saying the requested HTTP URL was not available. This is usually returned by a HTTP server that does not support the WS-Management protocol.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-CimSession SrcSrv01
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ConnectionError: (:) [New-CimSession], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80338113,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.NewCimSessionCommand
    + PSComputerName        : SrcSrv01
```

From DestSrv02 I can do a New-CIMSession SrvSrv01 and vice versa.  The issue is just with the CIM Session to the local netbios name.

What am I missing?